# python subprocess call OSX

Tags: python, bash, wifi

I am trying to access the wifi interface through python:
In bash I can use the following

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/sbin/airport -I
```

`-s` can also be passed.

I have tried using the following in python:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/sbin/airport', '-I'])
```

something is definitely not correct - as I get as a reply:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ip3.py", line 5, in <module>
    call(['/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/sbin/airport', '-I'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 467, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 741, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 1356, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/sbin/airport'
```

Any ideas would be welcome... I just want to begin by printing this to screen, saving as an array etc...

---

I dont have a high enough rating to answer my own question yet, so Ill say it here!

so I was being stupid!

```
from subprocess import call
call(['/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport', '-I'])
```

Works fine. Just needed to remove `/usr/sbin/airport`

Comment: isent the "/usr/sbin/airport" part an argument? anyway you can try with `shell=true`.

Comment: Nice, you got the ans by ur self :)

Comment: Thanks, I feel a bit stupid. Right after posting I looked at it again and noticed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call take first argument as command and subsequent arguments to that command.

In your case 
command is,
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport

and command's two arguments are,

1. /usr/sbin/airport
2. -I

So, you need to call it as,

```
from subprocess import call
call(['/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport' '/usr/sbin/airport', '-I'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
from subprocess import call
 call(['/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport', '/usr/sbin/airport', '-I'])
```

Otherwise it thinks `/usr/sbin/airport` is part of the first path.

Comment: I think this was because I was re-suing code that was for creating an alais to `/usr/sbin/airport` . It is definitely working without it.